# Does the Euler spiral - $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx^2} \, dx$ - Converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

I have a question about this integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}(1+i) $$

Essentially we are following this curve with -- the [Cornu spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral):

- $x = \cos t^2$
- $y = \sin t^2$

The Wikipedia article has an image, but I have some doubts.

- Does the red spiral really converge to the blue point?
- Or does it just approach a [limiting circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) with the blue point at the center?

[image]

---

See also:  **Orange  Peels and Fresnel Integrals** arXiv:[1202.3033](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3033)

Comment: Your integral equals, when $\Im\left[\text{k}\right]>0$:
$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{k}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\text{k}x^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{-\text{k}i}}$$

Comment: The parametrisation of the curve is $$t \mapsto \int_0^t e^{ix^2}\,dx.$$ Since the limit as $t \to \pm\infty$ exists …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the wikipedia page it is proved that $$\int^{\infty}_0\sin x^2 = \int^{\infty}_0\cos x^2 = \sqrt \frac \pi 8$$ so yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have just (24-Mar-17) posted an answer to another Cornu spiral question here: [Is this Cornu spiral positively oriented or not?.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978917/is-this-cornu-spiral-positively-oriented-or-not/2201856#2201856) It provides a closed-form analytic solution for the Cornu spiral and it is evident that the spiral does indeed approach the blue dots, albeit *very* slowly.